# Rails / MySQL - saving the total of an order is doubling the line items

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an order entry module:

Order has_many OrderLines

Everything works fine, except when I add a line at the bottom to update the cached total on the order, this doubles the order lines created.

a) I know it's not the transaction, this happens with and without it
b) I know it has nothing to do with the "sub_total_ordered" method I apply to the order as I put in a set rate of 100 and it still did it.
c) There are no before or after filters on either the Order or OrderLines.

Any ideas?

Edit* - I tried moving the @order.save to a OrderLine after_save filter and the problem goes away, but I still would like to know what is causing this.

```
  def create
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    OrderLine.transaction do
      params[:order_lines].each do |i, values|

          # If an orderline for the  sku already exists find it and update, otherwise initialize it
          ol = @order.order_lines.find_or_initialize_by_style_number(values[:style_number], values)

          # If its a new record and the qty_ordered is > 0 apply the order id then save it, otherwise delete it.

            if ol.new_record? && values[:qty_ordered].to_i > 0
              ol.order_id = @order.id
              ol.save!

          # If updating an existing order line and the qty_ordered is > 0 update it, otherwise delete it.
            else
              if values[:qty_ordered].to_i < 1
                ol.destroy
              else
                ol.update_attributes(values)
              end
            end
        end
      end
      # Update the cached_sub_total on the Order
      @order.cached_sub_total = @order.sub_total_ordered
      @order.save
    redirect_to order_path(@order)
  end
```

Here is the output (the bottom 4 lines is where you can see the orderlines inserted again.

```
Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  OrderLine Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `order_lines`.* FROM `order_lines` WHERE `order_lines`.`order_id` = 1 AND `order_lines`.`style_number` = 'F121' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `order_lines`.* FROM `order_lines` WHERE `order_lines`.`order_id` = 1 AND `order_lines`.`style_number` = 'F121' LIMIT 1
  Sku Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `skus`.* FROM `skus` WHERE `skus`.`sku_number` = 'F121' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE `skus` SET `qty_on_order` = 161, `updated_at` = '2012-03-20 02:56:01' WHERE `skus`.`id` = 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `order_lines` (`colour`, `created_at`, `order_id`, `price`, `product_size`, `qty_ordered`, `qty_shipped`, `style_number`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Black Suede', '2012-03-20 02:56:01', 1, 10, NULL, 9, NULL, 'F121', '2012-03-20 02:56:01')
  OrderLine Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `order_lines`.* FROM `order_lines` WHERE `order_lines`.`order_id` = 1 AND `order_lines`.`style_number` = 'F122' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `order_lines`.* FROM `order_lines` WHERE `order_lines`.`order_id` = 1 AND `order_lines`.`style_number` = 'F122' LIMIT 1
  Sku Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `skus`.* FROM `skus` WHERE `skus`.`sku_number` = 'F122' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  UPDATE `skus` SET `qty_on_order` = 172, `updated_at` = '2012-03-20 02:56:01' WHERE `skus`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `order_lines` (`colour`, `created_at`, `order_id`, `price`, `product_size`, `qty_ordered`, `qty_shipped`, `style_number`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Grey Suede', '2012-03-20 02:56:01', 1, 10, NULL, 9, NULL, 'F122', '2012-03-20 02:56:01')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM((ol.qty_ordered * ol.price)) AS sum_id FROM order_lines ol WHERE (ol.order_id = 1)
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `order_lines` (`colour`, `created_at`, `order_id`, `price`, `product_size`, `qty_ordered`, `qty_shipped`, `style_number`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Black Suede', '2012-03-20 02:56:01', 1, 10, NULL, 9, NULL, 'F121', '2012-03-20 02:56:01')
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `order_lines` (`colour`, `created_at`, `order_id`, `price`, `product_size`, `qty_ordered`, `qty_shipped`, `style_number`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Grey Suede', '2012-03-20 02:56:01', 1, 10, NULL, 9, NULL, 'F122', '2012-03-20 02:56:01')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```